# how to fetch process from python process pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to create many processes, 
each process runs 5 seconds later than a previous process, 
namely, the time interval between each process starts is 5 seconds,
so that:
run process 1
wait 5 seconds 
run process 2
wait 5 seconds
run process 3
wait 5 seconds
.....

like:

```
        for i in range(10):
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=func)
            p.start()
            sleep(5)
        #after all child process exit
        do_something()
```

but I want to call do_something() after all the process exit
I don't know how to do the synchronization here

with a python pool libary, I can have

```
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    for i in xrange(500):
            pool.apply_async(func, i)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    do_something()
```

but in this way, 4 processes will run simultaneously,
I can't decide the time interval between processes,
is it possible to create a process pool and then fetch each process, something like

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
for i in xrange(500):
    process = pool.fetch_one()
    process(func, i)
    time.sleep(5)
pool.close()
pool.join()
do_something()
```

are there such a library or source code snippets which satisfy my needs?
thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could add an argument to your func that is number of seconds to wait prior to processing? And calculate that value as 5 * i?

Comment: do you want to call `func` every 5 seconds 500 times? Why the delay? How long does an individual `func` call last? Do you want to limit the number of concurrent (simultaneous) calls? What happens if you add `time.sleep()` after `apply_async()`? What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: an individual `func` call lasts for 25 seconds. and I want to call `func` every 5 seconds for many times, maybe 500 maybe 1000.

Comment: How about adding `sleep(5)` in the loop inside the first piece of code you gave?

Comment: ah, I made a mistake, yes you are right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to put suggestions together, you could do something like:

```
plist = []
for i in range(10):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=func)
    p.start()
    plist.append(p)
    sleep(5)
for p in plist:
    p.join()
do_something()
```

You could give a timeout argument to `join()` in order to handle stuck processes; in that case you'd have to keep iterating through the list, removing terminated processes until the list is empty.